# R ggplot2 : alpha depending density value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a density map of events in San Francisco. I need to display hexagons. I need hexagons's alpha to be close to 1 when the density is maximum and close to 0 when the density is minimum. My try :

```
ggmap(sfmap, base_layer = ggplot(sample_ds, aes(x=long, y=lat))) +
  coord_cartesian() +
  stat_binhex() +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0,0.8)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red")
```

[image]

I would like the red hexagons to have a alpha value of 1 according to the big value of the count variable.
On the other hand I would like the yellow hexagons to have a value of alpha close to 0 because there is not a lot of event in those hexagons

And the

Very noob question, sorry, but I'completely lost with this package, I know it's powerful but I can't get a sense of what I do or where I should look for information.

Comment: Can you provide an output, sample data, or an expected result?

Comment: yeah sorry i'm a bit tired

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
library(ggmap)
map <- get_map()
df <- data.frame(
  lon = do.call(runif, as.list(setNames(c(1000, attr(map, "bb")[c(2,4)]), c("n", "min", "max")))),
  lat = do.call(runif, as.list(setNames(c(1000, attr(map, "bb")[c(1,3)]), c("n", "min", "max"))))
)
ggmap(map, base_layer = ggplot(df, aes(x=lon, y=lat))) +
  coord_cartesian() +
  stat_binhex(aes(alpha=..density..)) +
  scale_alpha(range = c(0,0.8)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red")
```

Comment: thks a lot! Do you know a good material to understand ggplot2. Because I wonder where I would to find this information !

Comment: Good question. It seems as if it's not documented. I remember it from http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_density.html